# Expand argument in scale_x_discrete with geom_jitter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying something that has already been bothering many before me, but mostly  for continuous scales, and mostly for the y-axis. These question come closest:

- [add different amount of extra space on both sides of discrete ggplot x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823526/add-different-amount-of-extra-space-on-both-sides-of-discrete-ggplot-x-axis)
- [extend limit for qualitative variable in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44192229/extend-limit-for-qualitative-variable-in-ggplot/44193143#44193143)

However, neither

- `scale_x_discrete(expand = ...)`
  nor
- `coord_cartesian(expand = ...)` change anything! (**Nothing** happens, actually)

What do I do wrong?

```
my_dat <- data.frame(x = 'x', y = rnorm(400))
ggplot(my_dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_jitter()
```

[image]

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

...

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2     ggbeeswarm_0.6.0 reshape2_1.4.3  
[4] stringr_1.2.0    ggplot2_2.2.1    lubridate_1.7.1 
[7] tidyr_0.7.1      purrr_0.2.4      dplyr_0.7.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: In your plot, the space shaded in red has nothing to do with expansion, so changing the `expand = ...` parameter won't affect anything. Change the width parameter in `geom_jitter` instead.

**Explanation**: If you check the help file for `geom_jitter()`, you'll see that the default jitter width is 40% of data resolution:

> ... defaults to 40% of the resolution of the data: this means the
>   jitter values will occupy 80% of the implied bins. Categorical data is
>   aligned on the integers, so a width or height of 0.5 will spread the
>   data so it's not possible to see the distinction between the
>   categories.

We can also illustrate this by varying the width parameter. Observe that with `width = 0.4` (default), there's space to the left & right of the blue points. With `width = 0.5`, the red points go all the way to the ends:

```
ggplot(my_dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.4, color = "blue") +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.5, color = "red")
```

[image: plot]

As for the `expand = ...` parameter in `scale_x_discrete` / `coord_cartesian`, they do make a difference... **if** your axis has more than 1 value:

```
my_dat2 <- my_dat
my_dat2$x <- sample(c('y', 'z'), size = 400, replace = TRUE)

p2 <- ggplot(my_dat2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.4, color = "blue") +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.5, color = "red")
```

The plot parameters are same, but now there are two possible factor values along the x-axis. Observe that while there's no distinct break in red points (with `width = 0.5`) ***between*** category y & category z, there's an ***additional*** clear gap to the left and right. That's the space resulting from expansion:

```
set.seed(1) # set seed for consistent jitter values in each plot
p2
```

[image: plot 1]

Set horizontal expansion to `c(0, 0)`, and the gap disappears. Now the red points go all the way to the left / right edges:

```
set.seed(1)
p2 +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image: plot 2]

Set `expand = FALSE` in `coord_cartesian`, and vertical expansion disappears as well. Now the red points go all the way to the edge in all four directions:

```
set.seed(1)
p2 +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image: plot 3]

(In all three cases, the blue points with default jitter width of 0.4 do not reach the edge, because they are only supposed to occupy 80% of the implied bin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `oob` option as well.  See http://www.hafro.is/~einarhj/education/ggplot2/scales.html for some examples (search for `oob` on the page.)